# Automate SoundCloud using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nonetype

I'm learning how to automate websites using selenium but getting 'NoneType' Error.

```
selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/")
```

When I try to focus the search Bar get "NoneType Error"

[image: NoneType Error image]

Xpath copy chrome Developer Tool
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/")
```

Problem is here you have assign `driver.get()` in a `variable` which is again `driver` and which is having no attribute `find_element_by_xpath()`

Just change this. It will navigate to webpage.

```
driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath")
```